# Do I need to check for valid sessions in every controller in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Suppose in a web applicaiton by Spring Mvc do we need to check for valid sessions in every controller or in jsps too? How can i solve this session management thing in MVC? What do we basically do?
What are the other things which can add extra security to my application?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  How do sessions relate to security in your application?

Comment: how do i achieve session management?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague.  But you might consider looking up Spring Security.

Answer (score 2):

We usually check if session is expired in the filter layer and map it to the `DispatcherServlet`, this way, all the incoming request that will be handled by spring will be filtered first, and thus not allowing any interaction to a spring controller if session is already expired. If the session is found to be expired, send a redirect to a page where user will be informed that their session is already expired.

**Sample Filter code**

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter{
    ...
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (isSessionExpired((HttpServletRequest) theRequest)) {
            response.sendRedirect(((HttpServletRequest) theRequest).getContextPath() + "/expired.jsp");
            response.flushBuffer();
        }else{
            //..its not yet expired, continue
            theChain.doFilter(theRequest, theResp);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**Mapping to the `DispatcherServlet` in the web.xml**

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.mycompany.ourproject.filter.MyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>springdispatcher</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springdispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check authorization or authentification every session in every controller? You can use aspectj.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at spring's reference guide for session manangement and it is very simple to configure and straight forward http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html

Answer (score 0):

No you Do not need to check for valid sessions in every controller in Spring.

Spring framework makes session management very easy as you can just configure spring security in a single xml file and spring will take care of session management for you.

[Check out these examples on spring](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/p/spring-framework.html)