# How can I lock my Swagger UI page behind a login screen?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui

I've been trying to figure out a way that I can lock my swagger-ui.html page behind a login screen using Oauth 2.0 and eventually be able to identify a user through a JWT.

I've managed to figure out how to include an Authorize button, but I would prefer to not have the API methods be visible until successful login.  Is the best way around this just to redirect to a separate page with a login screen and is there a simple way to do this maybe in the Swagger config file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a middleware that looks for a token (could be JWT, or anything else) that is currently valid. If not valid, send the user through your auth mechanism (could be Oauth2 or something else).  This isn't unique to SwaggerUI -- it will work for any web application.

This answer talks about how to use the Spring MVC filter to check for session tokens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21592143/1168588

The mechanism to determine if a token is valid would be specific to your implementation.  JWT makes this easy by having the validation information self-contained.

(note - OAuth and JWT are not mutually exclusive - OAuth is a token exchange protocol, and JWT is a token format).